# Predicting Pixel Intensity Based on Surrounding Pixels

Tags: r, image

I am trying to build a model that will try to predict the pixel intensity at a particular point based off of the surrounding pixel intensities. As of now, the only way that I can think of doing this is averaging out the points, but I really don't think this is the best option. Someone suggested I try to use auto-regressive models, ARIMA I think, but I am not very familiar with the program. Would this be an appropriate program to use for what I need, if not, does anyone have any other suggestions for what I could use to do this in R?

Comment: ARIMA is used for time series modeling. I do not think that will work. But maybe I am wrong. Furthermore, that is not a question about programming. I do not think that is the right place for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the *spatstat* package: http://spatstat.github.io.

From the [FAQ](http://spatstat.github.io/FAQ.html), it supports using pixel image as data.

You should then be able to run spatial autoregression using the *spdep* package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spdep/index.html, in particular the *lagsarlm* function.